# what would be an efficient investment when central banks have massive qe?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, stock-market, federal-reserve

Recently the central bank said in a statement on its website. “Aggressive efforts must be taken across the public and private sectors to limit the losses to jobs and incomes and to promote a swift recovery once the disruptions abate.”

What would be an efficient investment strategy for the central bank to stimulate the economy? Please explain why?

Comment: With infinite money creation ability, your somewhat surreptitiously concealed premise that investment strategies need be 'efficient' does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

that is a really good question. One nuance to your answer might be found in this [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/economics-finance-domain/core-finance/money-and-banking/federal-reserve/v/more-on-quantitative-easing-and-credit-easing).

Basically, Ben Bernanke once defended the Fed's QE Program by saying, "What we did was *Qualitative* Easing, not Quantitative Easing." The Fed made a specific effort to buy securities like MBS after 2008. In a true QE Regime, the Fed would buy comic books if they could - they just want to pump money into the system.

Your Q is good, and one answer I can come up with: the Fed *might* want to buy specific [ABS](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/asset-backedsecurity.asp) like those packaging restaurant franchisee receivables. This is obviously because the food industry has fallen off a cliff - as have any securities associated with that industry. So, maybe `$1` spent buying those ABS is better than $1 of MBS, etc.